# How to use .isin and groupby in pandas

Tags: python, duplicates, pandas-groupby

```
P_id   F_name      L_name     DOB        dup_id
25     John        Doe        23/1/90     29  
28     John        Doe        23/1/90     29  
29     John        Doe        23/1/90     0  
35     Jane        Dawson     20/1/68     0  
47   Jane Matilda  Dawson     20/1/68     35
120    Shane         Jack     12/1/97     0
50     Belinda     Ada        11/11/11    145  
145    Belynda     Ada        11/11/11    0
65     Shayne M.   Jack       12/1/97     120
```

I am trying to check if dup_id(s) is found in a p_id, then group the dup_id(s) and the 'p_id' rows together. Grouping them by assigning a unique no to each group.

`for ind, val in df[p_id'].iteritems():
    if val in df['dup_id']:
        df5 = df.assign(id=(df['F_name'] + '_' + df['L_name']).astype('category').cat.codes)`

The above code doesn't work, it's just my attempt at it. 
This table is linked to other tables in the database using the p_id and I will need to merge or join them

The uid (new id) and will be used to group the records. I would have grouped them by fname and lname but because of the inconsistent name entries, I decided to use dup_id and p_id which is more reliable

New Output

```
P_id   F_name      L_name     DOB        dup_id       uid
25     John        Doe        23/1/90     29            1
28     John        Doe        23/1/90     29            1 
29     John        Doe        23/1/90     0             1  
35     Jane        Dawson     20/1/68     0             2  
47   Jane Matilda  Dawson     20/1/68     35            2
120    Shane       Jack       12/1/97     0             3
65     Shayne M.   Jack       12/1/97     120           3
50     Belinda     Ada        11/11/11    145           4 
145    Belynda     Ada        11/11/11    0             4
```

Comment: Can you show ([edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51036438/edit)) your desired output for your input dataframe?

Comment: @jpp thanks I just did

Comment: can't you replace dup_id with P_id whenever dup_id == 0, and then group by that?

Comment: @HaleemurAli ok thanks a lot... I didn't see it that way.. it worked.